# Is something like static this in c#

Tags: c#, static

I am working on project that had a lot of instance classes with only static methods.

```
public class TableA {    
    static void StaticCall() {}
}
```

I've implemented an interface ITable that has method a `Call()`

```
public interface ITable {    
    void Call() {}
}
```

which calls a static method `StaticCall()`.

```
public class TableA : ITable {    
    static void StaticCall() {}
    void Call() { TableA.StaticCall();}
}
```

Is there anyway that I don't have to write

```
TableA.StaticCall();
```

Instead I write

```
staticMagicNonExistingThisMaybeCallType.StaticCall();
```

I am looking for magic like static interface(I know it's stupid) or some generic magic using reflection which I don't know.

Please avoid any other answers that suggest to rewrite those static methods. Author didn't expect any further expansion and wrote generator that many users use to generate those static Tables.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Whats wrong the just doing `TableA.StaticCall`? What kind of object are you expecting to use?

Comment: Since you're in the same class, you can just call `StaticCall()` without specifying `TableA`.

Comment: Nothing except I have to do it about milion times. There are many classes that I have to update.

Comment: It looks like the intent here is to be able to pass around targetable table functions via ITable; I'm wondering if you might be able to accomplish this with lambdas, `Function<>` or `Action<>` objects? With that type, you could actually pass around `TableA.StaticCall` as an `Action<>` type. Does that help at all?

Comment: @zimdanen Of course I can. Thank you I didn't notice. Its pitty I can't thank you personaly. It saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a very creative answer to an old question, you can write a wrapper to assign to your magic variable:

```
public class StaticWrapper : DynamicObject {
  Type _type;
  public StaticWrapper(Type type) {
    _type = type;
  }
  public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result) {
    var method = _type.GetMethod(binder.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, args.Select(a => a.GetType()).ToArray(), null);
    if (method == null) return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
    result = method.Invoke(null, args);
    return true;
  }
  // also do properties ...
}
```

Usage in your context:

```
var magicType = new StaticWrapper(typeof(TableA));
magicType.StaticCall();
```

Source for wrapper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5205041/4154421

Comment: Thank you, perfect solution... It is a shame that I am forced to use .Net 3.5 framework.
At leas @zimmdaen pointed out the fact that I didn´t notice the fact that I don´t need it.