# MSAL TokenCacheHelper.cs failes to build because of "Protect" and "Unprotect"

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal

I'm am trying to use the provided C# MS Graph/MSAL application to create an application that utilizes the OneDrive API. I literally copy/pasted from the provided example code into my solution and I can't get the solution to build now.

I've ensured that the following NuGet packages are installed:

```
Microsoft.Graph
Microsoft.Identity.Client
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCache
Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts
```

I'm brand new to using MSAL and I'm sure this is just a dumb mistake on my part but any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Error Received:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Unprotect' and no accessible extension method 'Unprotect' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Test Case Designer  D:\code\Test Case Designer\TokenCacheHelper.cs  54  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Protect' and no accessible extension method 'Protect' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Test Case Designer  D:\code\Test Case Designer\TokenCacheHelper.cs  70  Active

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop;
using System.Windows;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal;

namespace Test_Case_Designer
{
    static class TokenCacheHelper
    {
        // <summary>
        // Path to the token cache
        // </summary>
        public static string CacheFilePath { get; private set; }
        public static object ProtectedData { get; private set; }

        private static readonly object FileLock = new object();

        private static void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            lock (FileLock)
            {
                args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                        ? ProtectedData.Unprotect(File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath),
                                                  null,
                                                  DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                        : null);
            }
        }

        public static void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
            if (args.HasStateChanged)
            {
                lock (FileLock)
                {
                    // reflect changes in the persistent store
                    File.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath,
                                       ProtectedData.Protect(args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3(),
                                                             null,
                                                             DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                                      );
                }
            }
        }

        internal static void EnableSerialization(ITokenCache tokenCache)
        {
            tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
            tokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `ProtectedData` is defined as an `object`.

This should have been [`System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

change

```
public static object ProtectedData { get; private set; }
```

to

```
private static ProtectedData protectedData;
public static ProtectedData GetProtectedData(){
    return protectedData;
}
```

should fix your issue.

Comment: You're right, that did get rid of the error I was getting with Unprotect and Protect, although now I see an error with get and private set

`error CS0722: 'ProtectedData': static types cannot be used as return types
error CS0721: 'ProtectedData': static types cannot be used as parameters`

Comment: @MichaelGonzales Instead of using property to limit setting scope, use `private static ProtectedData protectedData` and a function like `GetProtectedData` instead. I updated my answer. FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5188598/6670491